# What is the fastest way to extract all frames of video into images in C#?

Tags: c#, emgucv

I have created a application to extract every frame from a video. It is not perfect yet and has a lot of problems with it. One of the problems is how long it takes. It took a full 2 hours to extract the frames of a 3 minutes video and the original video was four minutes but it gave me a memory error after the video was nearly finished:

'OpenCV: Failed to allocate 2764800 bytes'

so, it takes a long time to complete the task and it has a few bugs
I am using Emgu.CV and MediaToolkit

Here is my code:

```
  using Emgu.CV;
  using MediaToolkit;
  using MediaToolkit.Model;



    string file;

    private void CreateFrames()
    {
        int i = 0;

        VideoCapture _video = new VideoCapture(file);
        var videoInfo = new MediaFile { Filename = file };
        using (var engine = new Engine()) { engine.GetMetadata(videoInfo); }

        while (i <= videoInfo.Metadata.Duration.Milliseconds * videoInfo.Metadata.VideoData.Fps)
        {
            Mat m = new Mat();
            _video.Read(m);
            _video.SetCaptureProperty(Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CapProp.PosFrames, i);
            preview.Image = _video.QueryFrame().ToBitmap();
            Bitmap bitmap = _video.QueryFrame().ToBitmap();
            bitmap.Save(String.Format(@"C:\\frames\\videoframe-{0}.png", i), 
    ImageFormat.Png);
            i++;
        }
    }

    private async void browse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult result = openFileDialog.ShowDialog();
        if (result == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            file = openFileDialog.FileName;
            var videoInfo = new MediaFile { Filename = file };
            using (var engine = new Engine()) { engine.GetMetadata(videoInfo); }
            label1.Text = videoInfo.Metadata.VideoData.Fps + "  \n" + 
         videoInfo.Metadata.Duration.ToString();

            // must be run on a second thread else it will not work and it will freeze
            Task getframes = new Task(CreateFrames);
            getframes.Start();
        }
    }
```

I would appreciate if somebody has a solution to make this faster and possibly a fix to the memory problem.

Comment: you never dispose Bitmaps that you `_video.QueryFrame().ToBitmap()` - this is your memory leak

Comment: _"Failed to allocate 2764800 bytes"_ - guess you video is 960x720 ?

Comment: I really don't know, but it seems that you have two calls to `_video.QueryFrame().ToBitmap()`, maybe it would be possible to reuse the Bitmap that is returned? Also, I guess the line `preview.Image = _video.QueryFrame().ToBitmap();` updates the GUI? This may be slow. And according to this documentation http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/3.0.0/document/html/2ec33afb-1d2b-cac1-ea60-0b4775e4574c.htm `QueryFrame()` returns a `Mat` object which seems to have `Save(...)` method, which may (?) be faster to call than first convering it to a `Bitmap` (allocating memory?) and then `Save` the `Bitmap`.

Comment: In the documentation for `PictureBox` there is an example which `Dispose` the image before displaying a new one. My gut feeling says that a significant amount of the 2 hours running your program is spent updating the `preview`. Try to run the program without the preview to see if it makes a difference. You can run the first x frames and measure what time it takes with / without preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, check for IDisposable objects without the "using". For example, Bitmap inherits from Image, that implements IDisposable. So, when using the bimap, your code should be like this:

```
using (Bitmap bitmap = _video.QueryFrame().ToBitmap())
{
    bitmap.Save(String.Format(@"C:\\frames\\videoframe-{0}.png", i), ImageFormat.Png);
}
```

Also check if the Mat class implements IDisposable. If it is the case, another using could help you with the memory problem.

For the performance issue, I really cant help, but 3 minutes video, at 60fps, are 10800 frames. 2 hours are 7200 seconds. So  0.6 seconds per frame. Is this really slow? Just asking, I have no idea...

Comment: Also, probably is better to use already tested tools as FFMpeg. See this other questions: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=extract+frames+ffmpeg

Answer (score 3):

Here is an implementation using just `Emgu.CV` (I am not familiar with `MediaToolKit`).

```
using (var video = new VideoCapture(file))
using (var img = new Mat())
{
    while (video.Grab())
    {
        video.Retrieve(img);
        var filename = Path.Combine(outputDirectory, $"{i}.png");
        CvInvoke.Imwrite(filename, img);
        i++;
    }
}
```

I tested this on a FullHD `mp4` video. Don't know the exact codec. This takes roughly 65ms per frame with my CPU (i7-8700k). But consider if you need to use the `png` format as it is slow to encode. If you don't want any compression loss and your harddisk is fast and big enough for `bmp`, it takes just 13ms per frame. `jpg` takes 40 ms.